# PineScript: Barcolor based on Input

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Complete newbie looking for help.

Currently I color my bars using a simple code.

```
barclr = input(false, title='(Off) Color2 or (On) Color1')
barcolor(barclr ? barcolor2 : barcolor1)
```

I now want to color bars only if another toggle says `"Yes"` and so I created,

```
bar = input.string("Yes", title="Colored Bars", options=["Yes", "No"]) == "Yes"
```

So now what I want to happen is when the `bar` dropdown is set to `"Yes"` then color bars otherwise don't color bars at all.

Also while `bar == "Yes"` then use `barclr` to switch between two options.

(I don't have a preference if it's a toggle or dropdown but just for my limited sense of differentiation I tried using a dropdown.)

I don't know how to put this together. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost accomplished a goal, add a new ternary check for the **bar** input and nest the existing ternary condition inside `barcolor()` function:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

bar = input.string("Yes", title="Colored Bars", options=["Yes", "No"])
barclr = input(false, title='(Off) Color2 or (On) Color1')

barcolor1 = color.red
barcolor2 = color.green

barcolor(bar == "Yes" ? barclr ? barcolor1 : barcolor2 : na)
```